# Creating a static instance variable for return type

Tags: java, performance

I have a game loop that runs approximately at 60 fps. In each iteration I need to call a bunch of methods from my utility class Physics. It looks like this

```
public final class Physics {

    private static final float G = 9.81f;
    private static Vector2D var1 = new Vector2D();

    private Physics() {
    }

    public static Vector2D method1(param1, param2, param3) {
        /*
         * Do some computations with param1, param2 and param3, 
         * then assign the result to var1
         */
        return var1;
    }
}
```

What are the pros and cons of this design pattern? Is it good to use var1 as a helper instance variable like what I did in the above code because if I put it inside `method1()` like the following

```
    public static Vector2D method1(param1, param2, param3) {
        Vector2D var1 = new Vector2D();
        /*
         * Do some computations with param1, param2 and param3, 
         * then assign the result to var1
         */
        return var1;
    }
```

every second I get 60 new objects of type `Vector2D` and I want to avoid garbage collection.

Comment: It depends on what "Do some computations" does and how you use the result of `method1`. You should use a profiler and test both options - you will probably realise that the two designs are equivalent performance-wise and decide to move on other parts of your code which are really performance sensitive.

Comment: Also note that using a `static` variable may create thread safety issues if you access the variable concurrently from several threads.

Comment: 'Static instance variable' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to minimize the variable scope (for readablility) unless there's a good reason not to or a significant performance benefit. In this case I assume Vector2D doesn't use much overhead and the performance benefit of making a static variable is probably negligable.

So if you don't plan to access var1 from somewhere else than in method1 I'd recommend your second design pattern. If possible you don't event have to declare the varable inside the method, like this:

```
public static Vector2D method1(param1, param2, param3) {
    // Do some computations, compute x and y, then assign the result to var1
    return new Vector2D(x, y);
}
```

In the end it's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the `Vector2D` constructor does something unusual then creating 60 instances a second will be completely irrelevant in performance terms. Aim for clarity in your code before considering performance.

Answer (score 1):

Making it static will almost certainly break things if you have multiple instances of `Physics`. If the goal is to reduce the number of objects created, you'll get the same effect from a non-static field:

```
private Vector2D var1 = new Vector2D();
```

If you want to reduce the number of objects you're creating, I would use the [Object Pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). Rather than constructing a new `Vector2D` every time you would request an object from the pool, which would either construct a new object or recycle an old one.

```
Vector2D obj = Vector2D.get(x, y, z ...);
```

The object pool in this case would be some kind of `Collection` as a static member of `Vector2D`. This relies on `Vector2D` instances [being immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which [they should be](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html) anyway.

---

This is somewhat extreme if you've not tested and ensured that this object creation is actually a problem. Never optimise code for performance unless you *know* there is a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need to run your code for 60 times a second, you mast think for this ONE important thing that can improve you code performance.

- Singleton design pattern (To get single instance for all over the application )

It is recommended to use Singleton instance when you are not doing any extraordinary computation rather just calling a method to compute for you.

Using a singleton is worth if you just need an object of a class to call any particular method which has **nothing to do outside it's method scope**.
This means, if your `method1(param 1, ...)` is just executing based ONLY ON THE GIVEN VALUES and NOT AFFECTING ANY OTHER INSTANCE VARIABLE or NOT CALLING ANY OTHER Non-Singleton class members, then you must go for singleton design pattern.

Read again if its confusing.